# Javascript string reg expression

Tags: javascript, string, replace, char, match

This is my string:

```
[FULL-TIME] Bytovia Bytow 0:0 Skra Czestochowa
```

I would to get text from two points, so my result will be:

```
Bytovia Bytow
```

I tried with

```
  var str = "[FULL-TIME] Bytovia Bytow 0:0 Skra Czestochowa"; 
  var res = str.replace("[FULL-TIME]", "");
  var res2 = res.match(/\w+ /);
  //but log is Bytovia and not Bytovia Bytow
```

Comment: You can add another str.replace to remove the text after 'Bytow'. Not really sure why you want to use regex.

Comment: Because I compare Bytovia Bytow with another Bytovia Bytow. If I compare only Bytovia or BytoviaBytow in one day it is possible that there is also Bytovia Bytow Women and also because I work with an api json

Answer (score 0):

How about changing you're regex to something like this.

```
var res2 = res.match(/([a-zA-Z ]+){2}/);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need to get the name of the team on the left. Here's a one-liner:

```
const res = str.match(new RegExp('(?:\\[FULL-TIME\\] )([a-z ]+)', 'i'))[1].trim();
```

Here    `(?:\\[FULL-TIME\\] )` - is not capturing group. Match won't, group is used readability, you may omit it like that if you want:

```
const res = str.match(new RegExp('\\[FULL-TIME\\] ([a-z ]+)', 'i'))[1].trim();
```

then `([a-z ]+)` will match one or more a-z chars or space symbols case insensitive (mind `'i'` flag as the second parameter to `RegExp` constructor). This is a capturing group which will go to `[1]` index of the array returned by `String.prototype.match`.

The rest of the story is simple - we grab the value index `[1]` and trim it to get rid of any trailing or preceding spaces.

UPD: as for the second team you will need another capturing group:

```
const str = "[FULL-TIME] Bytovia Bytow 0:0 Skra Czestochowa";
const match = str.match(new RegExp('(?:\\[FULL-TIME\\] )([a-z ]+)\\d+:\\d+([a-z ]+)', 'i'))
const team1 = match[1].trim(); // => Bytovia Bytow 
const team2 = match[2].trim(); // => Skra Czestochow
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is much easier if you don't use regex at all. You can just split the string and get the words that way. For example:

```js
var str = "[FULL-TIME] Bytovia Bytow 0:0 Skra Czestochowa";
var sp = str.split(" ");
var firstWord = sp[1];
var secondWord = sp[2];
```

Of course, this is assuming that all the strings you are using, only have two words to extract (ex. Bytovia Bytow).

Since you asked how to do this with **regex**, I think that this will do the trick:

```js
var str = "[FULL-TIME] Bytovia Bytow 0:0 Skra Czestochowa"; 
var res = str.replace("[FULL-TIME]", "");
var res2 = res.match(/.*(?= [0-9]*:)/);
```

**Explanation:**

`.*` - will match any character

`(?= [0-9]*:)` - it will look ahead and search for a space, followed by either zero or more digits, next to a colon.

So even if you need to match multiple words, not just two, this should find all of them.

Comment: That's perfect! But now I also would to get the second team `Skra Czestochowa`.
I tried with this `res.match(/:\w+.*(?=)/)` and the result is `:0 Skra Czestochowa`.what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of the lookahead regex, you need the lookbehind. So to get the string, you should write `res.match(/((?<=:[0-9] |:[0-9][0-9] ).*/)`. When it comes to the lookbehind, you can't match strings with a variable length. That's why I have one `:[0-9] ` which will look for colon followed by a digit and a space, or a colon, then two digits followed by a space. This should give you the result you need. Also, if all the strings are of this format, it would be easier to match it with `(?<=[0-9] )`. Just skip a digit followed by a space and get everything after that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str = "[FULL-TIME] Bytovia Bytow 0:0 Skra Czestochowa"; 
var res = str.replace("[FULL-TIME]", "");

// Modified Statement
var res2 = res.match(/\w+\s\w+/);
```

For further exploration, you may try this:

- https://regexr.com/